# a.push is not a function; a.shift is not a function; a.splice is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have looked around, and have not been able to figure out why I'm throwing this error on this simple rotation algorithm. Happens with .push, .shift, .splice. Pls help! (I am aware there are more efficient ways to solve, just want to understand why I can't get these methods to work!)

```
function rotation(n, d) {
  var a = []
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    a += i
  };

  for (x = 1; x <= d; x++) {
    a.push(a[0]);
    a.shift();
  }
  console.log(a)
}
rotation(5, 4)
```

Answer (score 9):

`a += i` means `a = a + i`. `+` has no special meaning for arrays. By using `+`, you're coercing to a primitive — a string, in this case — and doing string concatenation. Since then `a` refers to a string, not an array, it doesn't have array methods.

If you want to add an element, use `push`, not `+`:

```
for(i=1; i <= n; i++){
    a.push(i);
}
```

---

Also note that semicolons (`;`) *don't* go at the end of control-flow statements with blocks attached, and *do* go at the end of all other statements (for instance, your original `a += i`, the `console.log` near the end, etc.).